# Emulating sudo's behaviour with su

Tags: bash, shell, su

I'm trying to write a wrapper around `su` to make it more like `sudo`, so that `su_wrapper foo bar baz` == `su -c "foo bar baz"`.

However, I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I came up with this:

```
su_wrapper ()
{
  su -c "$@"
}
```

However, in the above, only a single argument can be there; this fails with multiple arguments (as `su` sees them as its own arguments).

There's also another problem: since the argument is passed through the shell, I think I must explicitly specify the shell to avoid other problems. Perhaps what I want to do could be expressed in pseudo-bash(!) as `su -c 'bash -c "$@"'`.

So, how could I make it accept multiple arguments?

Comment: your motivation being?...

Comment: @shx2, I'm really tired of having to quote things when using su, and I'm not allowed to use sudo on these boxes.

Comment: (for the record, it isn't clear to me why people voted to close. this is about general computing. `su` and `sudo` are tools used by programmers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf "%q"` to escape the parameters so they can be used as string input to your function:

```
su_wrapper() {
    su -s /bin/bash -c "$(printf "%q " "$@")"
}
```

Unlike `$*`, this works even when the parameters contain special characters and whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You need `$*` and not `$@`:

```
su_wrapper() {
    local IFS=' '
    su -c "$*"
}
```

See the [*Special Parameters* section in the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002a) for the difference between `$*` and `$@`.

I added `local IFS=' '` just in case `IFS` is set to something else (after reading what `$*` does, it should be clear why you want to make sure that `IFS` is set to a space).

Comment: This would fail for `su_wrapper ls "foo bar"` and `su_wrapper find . -name '.*'`

Comment: @thatotherguy you're right, but you can always properly quote the arguments to obtain what you want.

Comment: But you have to quote them twice, unlike sudo.

Comment: @thatotherguy right, but the counterpart is that redirection is much easier: `su_wrapper "ls > file"`, no need to fiddle with `tee` or similar artifice. So what you lose on one side, you gain it on the other side. Choose your side `:)`.

Comment: If you want to pass in an entire, quoted command, why not just use su?